# php rotating an image with transparency

Tags: php, rotation, gd, transparent

There are several posts I've found about rotating images with transparency in php. However, they all and up turning the transparent part of the image black.

The part that was replaced when rotated is transparent (the `imagerotate` function `$transparency` variable is working correctly, but the original image itself doesn't stay transparent. In this image, the white area (replaced with imagerotate) is transparent, as it should be, but the black area should also be transparent:

[image]

Thanks  for the help. My code is below.

```
<?php

//$mapim=imagecreatefrompng('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.039299261014,-76.112831236771&zoom=20&size=600x600&sensor=false&maptype=satellite');
$panel=base64_decode('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');

//ob_start();
$degrees=60;
$srcpanelim=imagecreatefromstring($panel);
$panelim=imagecreatetruecolor(600,600);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($panelim,0,0,0,127);
imagealphablending( $panelim, false );
imagesavealpha( $panelim, true );
imagecopyresampled($panelim,$srcpanelim,0,0,0,0,600,600,600,600);
ob_start();
    imagepng($panelim, NULL, 9);
    $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();
    echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($rawImageBytes ) . "' />";
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($panelim,0,0,0,127);
$panelim = imagerotate( $panelim, $degrees, $transparency, 1);

ob_start();
//header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
imagepng( $panelim );
$rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();
    echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($rawImageBytes ) . "' />";  
imagedestroy( $panelim );

/*$panelim
ob_start();
    imagepng($panelim, NULL, 9);
    $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();
    echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($rawImageBytes ) . "' />";
    */


?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use Imagecopy merge instead of imagecopyresampled. Imagecopyresample does the same as imagecopy plus an additional resample. The problem here is that iamgecopy does not work with transparancy..

you can find a note on php.net about this here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php